# Bulk-reverse the order of headers in Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to bulk-reverse the order of headings in Emacs org-mode? 
I'd like to change this kind of list (**but much bigger, not just two or three items, thus "bulk"**):

```
* personal computer
 * Windows
 * Mac
 * Linux
* StackExchange
 * stackoverflow
* countries
* people
```

to this:

```
* people
* countries
* StackExchange
 * stackoverflow
* personal computer
 * Windows
 * Mac
 * Linux
```

Answer (score 9):

Select the whole buffer and use `M-x org-sort-entries RET F point RET`

`org-sort-entries` sorts all items at a certain level in the tree. 'F' tells it that you want to sort in reverse order according to a function that you specify. Using the function `point` gives each entry a value corresponding to buffer position on which to sort.

To do the same thing from elisp, the equivalent function call is `(org-sort-entries nil ?F 'point)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I asked this question on emacs stackexchange and I got an answer with a complete function which can do this operation with one call and no extra keystrokes like F and returns. However, I wonder how could I have made *this* in to a function. I've put together a function where I wrote `(org-sort-entries "F" "point")` but it gives an error that says `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, "point".`  I even changed the `"point"` into `'point` but didn't work either.

Comment: The best way to figure out the elisp is to use the function documentation in the help system, `C-h f org-sort-entries`. In this case, it shows that the first parameter is WITH-CASE. It's set via the prefix argument when the function is called interactively, but needs to be set explicitly when called from elisp. I've edited the answer to show it.

Answer (score 4):

`C-c ^` to invoke `org-sort`, which will Call `org-sort-entries`, `org-table-sort-lines` or `org-sort-list` accordingly.

Then you can either:

- f point RET `>` RET
- F point RET `<` RET

*I don't know the org-sort-entries' api changed or what, when I followed @clatter's answer, it asked me for a compactor. So here is an answer basing on his.*

Answer (score -1):

Sure, `M-S-<up>` and `M-S-<down>` move subtrees up and down inside their common parent. There are a bunch of other similar commands as well; check out the info page for a list of them (`M-x info "(org) Structure Editing"`).

Edit: Actually reversing the order of subheadings is not something you can do out of the box, I think. You might be able to do it by calling `sort-subr` with cleverly chosen arguments, however.

Comment: Thanks, but no, as I wrote at the end, the actual list I'm going to sort is a lot bigger and it has more than 100 first-level headers. I just want to reverse the list so that the last heading with its subtrees would be the first heading of a new list, second-last would be the second heading of the new list, and so on.  It'd be a lot of work to sort them manually.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear; from the example it looked like you just wanted to move a subheading around, and 'reverse' was just poor word choice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, so my English is not very good. What would be a better word choice in this situation? Or is the "order" weird rather than the "reverse?" How about "reverse-sort?"

Comment: Or did the word "quickly" sound like I'm going to move just one or two headings around and done?

Comment: Reverse is the right word, and now that you've fixed your example it's much clearer.